# Angular ui-select fires duplicate $http request in ui-select-choices

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ui-select, ui-select2

I am trying to use ui-select in my project, but this time a function of controller will be passed to ui-select-choices as a options. See below:

**HTML:**

```
<ui-select ng-model="selectedItem" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;" title="Please select">
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select">{{$select.selected}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="item in ctr.listItem()">
  <span ng-bind-html="item">{{item}}</span>
</ui-select-choices>
```

**Controller:**

```
vm.listItem = function() {
console.log("lisItem() called");

$http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "/pma/api/listyear"
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    return response.data;
});
```

What I noticed from the debugger of chrome is the browser sending mulitple $http request even I just have a single ui-select element in the page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use a function in angular HTML template, expect it to be called every `digest`. In this case you should assign the results to a variable and use that variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I have noticed ui-select provides `refresh` tag to reload the content by calling the function so that it can support dynamic choices. Back to my previous example, following is the new code to achieve what I need:

```
<ui-select ng-model="selectedItem" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled"
      style="width: 300px;" title="Please select">
     <ui-select-match placeholder="Select">{{$select.selected}}</ui-select-match>
     <ui-select-choices repeat="item in ctr.items" refresh="ctr.listItem()"  refresh-delay="0">
     <span ng-bind-html="item">{{item}}</span>
     </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```